# Firing click event using `fireEvent` in IE with a detached anchor node

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

This question has been asked before in relation to simulating a click event on an anchor **already in the DOM**. My question is how to simulate a click event on **a detached node**.

This works in every browser so far except IE9 and below. This is a standalone HTML file reproducing the issue (I'm using IE8 to test):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            function goToBlankPage() {
                // Create link in memory
                var a = window.document.createElement("a");
                a.target = '_blank';
                a.href = "http://google.com/";

                // Dispatch fake click
                if (window.document.createEvent) {
                    var e = window.document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                    e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                    a.dispatchEvent(e);
                } else if (window.document.createEventObject) {
                    try {
                        var parentEl = document.createElement("div");
                        parentEl.appendChild(a);

                        var clickEvent = document.createEventObject();            
                        clickEvent.button = 1; // left mouse button
                        a.fireEvent('onclick', clickEvent);

                    } catch(ex) {
                        alert(ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>

        <a href="javascript:goToBlankPage()">Blank Page</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

I had to assign a parent otherwise I was getting **Error: Unspecified Error** in my alert.

Any ideas?

Comment: With `<a>` element, you can just use `a.click()`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would one click a node in memory?

Comment: I have no idea, I just need a way to open an arbitrary URL in a new tab and this is what worked for my particular case, just not in IE.

Comment: @duri, maybe if it's attached to the DOM, but it doesn't work with a detached anchor.

Comment: If you can also figure out a way to attach it to the DOM and click it, that works too. ANY WAY to just open a URL in a new tab, without using `window.showDialog`/`window.open`, will work for me.